# Saving time in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, date, foundation, userdefaults

I'm working on a little game. When the user has a game going and shuts down the game, the app saves a timestamp so when he returns it can calculate, in seconds, for how long time he was away.

My problem is, that when the app re-opens it crashes. I can see that it's a conversion issue, but I tried various things that did not work.

So my last hope is Stack Overflow. :-)

My code is as following:
In the AppDelegate.swift file it saves the date:

```
appData.set(Date(), forKey: GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp)
```

And when the user re-opens the app (still AppDelegate.swift)

```
GameScene().calculateTimeLeft()
```

And finally my GameScene.swift:

```
let timeSinceActive = appData.object(forKey: GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp)!
/* Check the difference */
let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(timeSinceActive as! Date)
/* Convert this to seconds */
let timeSpentAwayInSeconds = Int(elapsedTime)
/* Find out how many seconds the user had left when he quitted the game */
let currentTimeLeft = appData.integer(forKey: GameData.currentTimeLeft)
/* If the time spent away is larger than the seconds there was left, the game is over */
if timeSpentAwayInSeconds > currentTimeLeft {
    /* Game over */
    appData.set(0, forKey: GameData.currentTimeLeft)

    GameOver()
}
```

**Edit:**

Forgot to paste the log:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x1b8c90f30) to 'NSDate' (0x1b8c91b10).
2017-08-29 20:16:49.533396+0200 Sleepy[929:226885] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x1b8c90f30) to 'NSDate' (0x1b8c91b10).
```

Comment: If I use a simplified version of your code in a playground it seems to work OK. (Is `appData` just `UserDefaults.standard`?)

Comment: Hm, that's very odd indeed. Yeah, I just made "appData" as a "shortcut" :-)

Comment: Maybe you accidentally write something else using key GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp? After you've written the date.

Comment: @user2026507 - I suggest setting a breakpoint that lets you see what data type (and content) comes back from `appData.object`.

Comment: Are you setting `GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp` from some where else and when you are resetting it?

Answer (score 20):

This code worked for me:

```
let app = UserDefaults.standard
let date = Date()
app.set(date, forKey: "date")

if let date2 = app.object(forKey: "date") as? Date {
  Date().timeIntervalSince(date2)
}
```

Instead of force unwrapping the variables use more features like `if let`, `guard let`, etc. This avoid crashing your application if the cast fails

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't recommend saving `Date()` as a value inside of UserDefaults, I'd try going for something that can more easily be serialized back and forth like strings or ints.

Try replacing:

```
appData.set(Date(), forKey: GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp)
```

with

```
appData.set(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: GameData.lastTimeActiveStamp)
```

Comment: The UserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, **NSDate**, NSArray, or NSDictionary. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults